# Request a bookmark from url always post error message

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I am trying to get the bookmark with the funtion:

```
- (void)getUrlBookMark:(NSString *)urlStr {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
    NSArray *keys = @[NSURLLocalizedNameKey, NSURLContentAccessDateKey,    NSURLContentModificationDateKey];
    NSData *bookmark = [url   bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationSuitableForBookmarkFile  includingResourceValuesForKeys:keys relativeToURL:nil error:nil];
    NSLog(@"bookmark: %@", bookmark);
}
```

I get the data successfully, but , always, an error message shows:

```
[default] [ERROR] Could not create a bookmark: Error Domain=NSFileProviderInternalErrorDomain Code=0 "NoValidProviderFound_url" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=NoValidProviderFound_url}
```

it seems that the url I provide is wrong, but I have got the right bookmark already, so I don`t know the reason and how to fix it.

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain "it seems that the url I provide is wrong" - why? where does the string come from? etc. - and "I have got the right bookmark already" - why are you getting it again then? is this bookmark for use with the sandbox? etc. With this extra information someone will probably be able to help you. (Don't put your answers in comments, edit the question itself, you may add a comment to let people know you've made the edits.)